# Slow Execution Time Batch .xlsx to .xls Conversion

Tags: excel, execution-time, vba

I have written this code to batch convert a bunch of .xlsx workbooks to .xls (I have a lot of end users using 2003). It does the job but it is very slow, I tested this on 20 workbooks each only about 30 kb in size and it took 9.78 seconds to execute locally. Through my sharepoint server this took 262 seconds but I believe the incredibly slow speed for sharepoint is a different issue.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Convert_to972003()
    Dim orgwb As Workbook
    Dim mypath As String, strfilename As String
    Dim nname As String

    '--> Error Handling
    On Error GoTo WhatHappened

    '--> Disable Alerts
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    '--> Specify location of workbooks
    mypath = "C:\xxx"
    strfilename = Dir(mypath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    '--> Check the specified folder contains files
    If Len(strfilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    '--> Start Loop, end when last file reached
    Do Until strfilename = ""

    '--> Open a workbook
        Set orgwb = Application.Workbooks.Open _
        (mypath & "\" & strfilename)

        '--> Create new Filename, Save in new File Format and Close
        nname = Replace(strfilename, ".xlsx", ".xls")
        orgwb.SaveAs mypath & "\" & nname, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        orgwb.Close
        strfilename = Dir()
    Loop

    '--> Enable Alerts
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

Exit Sub

WhatHappened: MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

**Question**

Is there a quicker method to convert file formats than looping through the folder/opening/saving/closing?

Comment: [Microsoft office Compatibility pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) saves you having to convert

Comment: True but this saves all my end users having to install it which for some would probably be beyond them..

Comment: Would your xlsx file have formats or just plain data?

Comment: The files I'm currently applying it to have plain data.

Comment: Why not use OLEDB to convert xlsx files to CSV then? The conversion will happen in blink of an eye and the files can be read in Excel 2003

Comment: Not familiar with it, reading up on official site, can you point me towards any other resources?

Comment: Lemme see if I can give you a VBA example. But first.. will csv do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16553/discussion-between-alistair-weir-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 3):

If this is still relevant. When I had a similar problem I ended up with nearly the same code, but what helped me to speed it up a little was to disable [`Application.EnableEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx), i.e.:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

in the appropriate parts. This is especially helpful if you have any other add-ins or macros which are triggered by various Excel events like opening or closing a workbook etc.

Comment: Yes this helps speed up a little but I was attempting to find a different approach which I don't really think is possible.